# Function not working as expected - both elements not reflecting arguments passed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function in which I am looking to animate multiple progress bars.  When testing with just one ID the progress bar works as expected (i.e if I want the bar to go to only 80% widht it will) but when I try to call the function a second time with different arguements the progress bar for both ID's go to 100. instead of elem1 at 80% and elem 2 at 100%.

I know this is a long way to code this function but it is more for practice purposes.

So any advice as to why when the function is called twice it goes to 100 width on both elements instead of the predetermined values passed as arguments into the function calls?

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById('myBarOne');
var elem2 = document.getElementById('myBarTwo');

$('#btn').click(function() {
    move(elem1, 80);
    move(elem2, 100);
});

function move(id, fig) {
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= fig) {
        clearInterval(id);
        } else {
        width++;
        elem1.style.width = width + '%';
        elem2.style.width = width + '%';
        } 
    }
}


<div id="myProgress">
   <div id="myBarOne"></div>
</div>
<div id="myProgress">
   <div id="myBarTwo"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Run</button>
```

Comment: what? `move(id, fig)` **&&** `var id = setInterval(frame, 10);` what??? rename `var id`. Also **ID** should be unique, you have two **myProgress**

Comment: Yep totally correct, that was the issue!  I had named the paramater as ID when it should have been 'elem' and then just chaged to elem.style.width = width + '%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `function move(id, fig)` on `function move(elem1, fig)`.